# Does this power sequence converge or diverge? If it converges, what is the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I have this sequence:

$$a_n = \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3 + 4n}}$$

Again, I don't think I can divide the numerator and denominator by $n^{1.5}$... that seems like it complicates things. What else can I do?

I can't square the top and bottom because that changes the value of the general sequence. Can I divide by $n^2$?

Is this valid:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n^3}{n^4} + \frac{4}{n}}}$$

Comment: What are you trying to do with the sequence? Are you trying to determine if it converges / find its limit? In your last identity, you should have $4/n^3$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find a divergent minorant:

$$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3 + 4n}} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3 + 4n^\color{blue}{3}}} = \sqrt{\frac{n}{5}} \to +\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: It is $$\sqrt{\frac{n^4}{n^3+4n}}$$ and this is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n} }{\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{n^2}}}$$

You can see that the denominator tends to 1, so that $a_n$ clearly diverges, behaving asymptotically as $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: How did you get to here?

Comment: Multiply by $\frac{n^{1.5}}{n^{1.5}}$.

Comment: Can you flesh that out a bit? Don't you mean divide top and bottom by $n^{1.5}$